Temporal Table Time ranges meet after changing a value for a period of time
I have a temporal table in MariaDB that contains application time.
create or replace table Contracts (
Event_ID Integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Employee_ID integer NOT NULL,
Working_hours integer,
Contract_Begin Date,
Contract_End Date,
Period for valid_time(Contract_Begin, Contract_End),
unique (Employee_ID,Working_hours, valid_time without overlaps))engine=innoDB default CHARSET utf8;

I insert the following values:
INSERT INTO Contracts (Employee_ID, Working_hours, Contract_Begin, Contract_End) VALUES (1, 100, '2024-05-01', '2024-08-31');

Now to update the working hours for June and July to the value of "145" I do the following:
update contracts  for portion of valid_time from '2024-06-01' to '2024-07-31' set Working_hours = 145 where Employee_ID = 1;

I am however not happy with the result. If I query:
select * from contracts; 
This is what I get:


"Event_ID","Employee_ID","Working_hours","Contract_Begin","Contract_End"
2,1,100,2024-05-01,2024-06-01
3,1,100,2024-07-31,2024-08-31
1,1,145,2024-06-01,2024-07-31



The Problem here is that the end date of first portion ('2024-06-01') equals the begin_date of the updated portion. So there is an overlap of one day and I get two results if I query for the working_hours for the '2024-06-01'. My aim however is to get no overlaps at all. The working_hours = 145 should hold for the entire range '2024-06-01' to '2024-07-31' and the end date of the portion before should be set to: '2024-05-31' And the start date of the portion after the change should be set to: '2024-08-01' - instead of '2024-07-31'. I think this is a very standard use case whenever there can only be one value at a specific time range.

Please publish the result of select version();

I haven't used this feature, can't install a suitable version of mariadb and can't find a fiddle that supports such a construct so cannot reproduce. Have you found a working fiddle or are you just doing this locally?

I do this locally on Mariadb Version 11.3. The temporal features of Mariadb are described here

I like to use this pattern:
WHERE dt >= '2024-06-01'
  AND dt  < '2024-06-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY

Note that BETWEEN is inclusive.
Note that that pattern avoids the messiness of leap days, etc.
